# ExpressJS undefined on post form

Tags: javascript, express

i don't know how to fix this, i made a form and trying to do "post" with parameters "name", but i get "undefined", tried everything that is on internet but can't fix

File: app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var almuerzo = require('./routes/almuerzo');

var app = express();
//DB Connect
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/comedorDB");

//Load all files in models dir

fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').forEach(function (filename) {
  if(~filename.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/models/' + filename);
});
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/comida', almuerzo);
```

file: almuerzo.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('comida');
});
router.post("/", function (req,resp) {
    resp.send('nombre: '+req.body.nombre);
    // resp.render("comida");
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i try to send "post" form postman chrome extension it works (content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded) but when i try from my form:

```
extends layout

block takami
    .container-fluid
        .row
            .col-md-12
                h3 Guardar  almuerzo
                form(method="post", action="/comida")
                    fieldset.form-group
                        label(for='nombre') Nombre de Comida
                        input#nombre.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Nombre')
                    fieldset.form-group
                        label(for='tipo') Tipo de comida
                        input#tipo.form-control(type='text', placeholder='tipo de comida')
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

This is my chrome browser header info:

```
POST /comida HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:3000/comida
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jade really, but it looks like your inputs are missing the name attribute.

Comment: Thats it! thanks man, i'm new on this too, now it works